# How can I create set contain id record in first set equal id record in second set?

Tags: c#

In database I have two tables:

```
public partial class PersonOne
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonTwo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to fill my set:

```
public class PersonOnePersonTwo
{
    public int PersonOneId { get; set; }
    public int PersonTwoId { get; set; }
}
```

where **PersonOne.name == PersonTwo.firstname && PersonOne.surname == PersonTwo.lastname** but I have no idea how I can do that - because below code isn't efficient and is so slow:

```
    List<PersonOne> personOneList = new List<PersonOne>();
    List<PersonTwo> personTwoList = new List<PersonTwo>();

    List<PersonOnePersonTwo> personOnePersonTwoList = new List<PersonOnePersonTwo>();

foreach (PersonOne personOne in personOneList)
{
    foreach(PersonTwo personTwo in personTwoList.Where(x => x.firstname == personOne.name && x.lastname == personOne.surname).ToList())
    {
        personOnePersonTwoList.Add(new PersonOnePersonTwo
            {
                PersonOneId = personOne.id,
                PersonTwoId = personTwo.id
            });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = personOneList.Join
             (
                personTwoList, 
                person1 => new { Key1 = person1.Name, Key2 = person1.Surname }, 
                person2 => new { Key1 = person2.FirstName, Key2 = person2.LastName }, 
                (person1, person2) => new PersonOnePersonTwo { PersonOneId = person1.Id, PersonTwoId = person2.Id }
             ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
    var personOnePersonTwoList = new List<PersonOnePersonTwo>();

    foreach (var personOne in personOneList)
    {
        personOnePersonTwoList = personTwoList.Where(x => x.firstname.Equals(personOne.name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
                                                          x.lastname.Equals(personOne.surname, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                              .Select(x => new PersonOnePersonTwo {PersonOneId = personOne.id, PersonTwoId = x.id}).ToList();
    };
```

As a side note: it's more convinient to use Equals when comparing strings.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is too slow :/